# How send data in object to function in same object?

Tags: c#, class, object

I see this C# Source Code:

```
User user = new User();
User.Name = "asd";
User.EMail = "asd@yahoo.com";
User.Create();
```

My question: how i can send data to Create function ? i mean what code i must write it in create function ?

Comment: "send data to Create function"? Do you mean "pass arguments to Create function"?

Comment: exactly i mean how Create function receive data without send user object to Create function, i can do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to pass 'data' to your `create` method you need to rewrite it to something like this

```
public static string Create(User user)
```

and to call it

```
User.Create(user)
```

for more on this topic you should refer to

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx

Comment: you mean like this: User.Create(user); send object created by all saved data to Create function?

Comment: i added more info since you need to modify both the method and the code where you call it